# Red-Black tree: Split/Concatenate in log(n) time

Tags: algorithm, split, concatenation, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

According to Ron Wein your able to do split and concatenation of red-black tree's in O(log(n)) time. See his artikle: [Efficient Implementation of Red-Black Trees with Split and Catenate Operations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.4875&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

However I'm still not convinced that the running time of split really is true.

The idea is that split uses worst-case log(n) concatenatations. These concat's is done fast as we can find the node, p, by remembering the p, from last concatenate.

The problem is that concatenation starts the fix-up (balancing) algorithm, which as far as I know takes O(log n) (see step 5 in the pseudo-code for concatenation). 
This gives me a running time of log(n)*log(n), as split will make worst-case log(n) concatenations.

Ron Wein, does not take the fix-up algorithm into count in his argumentation. What have i missed in my analysis, or is the algorithm wrong?

Comment: Probably an amortization argument that implies that not every one of the fixups really is expensive

Comment: A good thought, but that was the case, the end result would at least be in amortized time, which it isn't. So dont think thats the case. But thanks for your answer

Comment: That's not what I mean. If you can bound the total work for fixup *within* the split operation (e.g. via amortization), you get a proper worst case bound for split.

Comment: Ahh I see - Good point. But can't see that is true.

Comment: "However, as we go down the tree we can easily go simultaneously down the rightmost path of T1 and the leftmost path of T2 and locate nodes that have the same black height as κ. Thus, each catenation operation is carried out in constant amortized time, and the total running time of the entire procedure is O(C log n)."

Comment: Yeah i understand that. What this says, is that the node, p, can be found by going down T1 and T2 while you go down the tree.

But log(n) concatenations still add a red pivot nodes, which we must do a fix-up on. And thats not included in that argument. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, the authors argue that the concats can be done in constant amortized time under the given circumstances. The complete argument is in the reference Tar83a.

Comment: OKay. Thanks. I have ordered the book, and hope to get it soon. THank for the help

Comment: Actually it's on Google Books, so you should be able to look at the interesting pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In future. If any have the same problem again:
Tarjan have some important differences in the algorithm compared to what Ron Wein does. I still haven't been able to see that Wein is correct in his algoritm, but Tarjan is. So I suggest you use his instead.

First important point is that the balancing algorithm cost O(log(d)) where d is the depth for which you start the balacing from.
Tarjan's algorithm then differs by starting at the split-key and moving on the path to root. By do this, you will see that the the subtree's you concatenate have about same depth. Thus will "d" always be small. Thus it is can be done much faster.

A second thing is that Tarjan suggest that all nodes is augmented such that they know their rank (black depth of its subtrees+it self). By doing this, we are able to know which tree is biggest in O(1) time. 
It is also possible to find the difference in there height in O(1) time.

I suggest all to read Tarjans paper instead of Wein's

Comment: Please, can you post a link to Tarjan's algorithm? I have some problem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Wein states in section 2 that insertion fix-up takes constant amortized time, citing Tarjan (1983): Updating balanced search tree in O(1) rotations. Thus, the O(log n) insertion fix-ups performed in the O(log n) concatenations will take O(log n) amortized time.

However, I can offer my own proof that they will take O(log n) (non-amortized) time per split operation. Let's track a node L as it moves down the left spine of T<sub>2</sub>. When we add in a pivot node when concatenating to T<sub>2</sub>, L is set to the left child of the pivot node. Whenever κ changes, L is set to the black node in the left spine of T<sub>2</sub> that is at the same black height as κ. We can show that the fix-ups in T<sub>2</sub> take O(log n) time using the potential method of analysis, where the potential function Φ is equal to the number of red nodes that are right children of nodes in the path from L to the root.

Let's show that the insertion fix-ups for T<sub>2</sub> take O(log n) time total in a given split operation. (By symmetry, this implies that they take O(log n) time for T<sub>1</sub>.) Initially, the potential function Φ is 0 (let's say), because T<sub>2</sub> is empty. Every time Φ increases by 1, we'll charge the current operation for work that will (possibly) be performed by some future operation that decreases Φ by 1.

There are three types of operations that affect the structure of T<sub>2</sub>, the colors of its nodes, or the value of L, and thus three types of operations that could possibly affect the value of Φ:

- Moving κ to one of its children.
- Adding a pivot node.
- Performing an insertion fix-up operation.

(We could think of inserting the final node into T<sub>2</sub> as a concatenate operation with the node as the pivot, or just treat it separately and observe that it contributes O(log n) to the total time spent in insertion fix-up.)

Let's compute the total cost of these three types of operations. Moving κ to one of its children causes L to stay the same (if it was already at the correct black height) or to move to either its left child if this is black, or the (black) left child of its left child. This increases Φ by at most 2, since it adds at most two nodes to the collection of nodes in the L-to-root path. So the cost of each move is O(1), plus up to 2 for the increase in Φ. There are O(log n) such moves (at most the height of the original tree), so the total cost is O(log n) * O(1) = O(log n).

Adding a pivot node (i.e. sticking a node in the left spine of T<sub>2</sub> and giving it two children, as part of a concatenate operation) adds up to three nodes to the collection of nodes in the L-to-root path: the pivot node, its parent, and its left child. It also removes up to one node from this collection: its right child. (This follows from analyzing all possible combinations of the colors of κ and its right child, before adding the pivot node. What really matters here is that L was a constant distance from the node that we made into the pivot node's right child.) So adding a pivot node increases Φ by at most 3, and the cost is at most O(1) + 3. We add pivot nodes O(log n) times (up to once for each node in the path that κ takes). So the total cost for adding pivot nodes is O(log n) * O(1) = O(log n).

Let's look at an insertion fix-up operation. We'll work off of the description depicted in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red–black_tree#Insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Insertion). The cost for cases I1, I3, and I4 is O(1), and none of them affects Φ. It is impossible to reach case I5, because the current node is always on the left spine of the tree. Case I6 increases Φ by 1, since the grandparent becomes a new red right child of a node in the L-to-root path. So the cost of case I6 is O(1) + 1. Case I2 decreases Φ by 1, since it changes the uncle from red to black. So the cost for case I2 is 1 - 1 = 0. The operation is free, meaning it is charged to some previous operation (either moving κ to one of its children, adding a pivot node, or reaching case I6 during a previous insertion fix-up operation).

The total cost of the insertion fix-up is the total cost for all six cases. Case I2 is reached O(log n) times, and the other cases are reached at most once, so the total cost is O(1) + O(log n) * 0 + O(1) + O(1) + 0 + O(1) = O(1). There are at most O(log n) insertion fix-ups (at most one for each node in the path that κ follows). Thus, the total running time for all three types of operations is O(log n) + O(log n) + O(log n) * O(1) = O(log n).