# Missing merge and split for boost AVL trees?

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost, avl-tree, intrusive-containers

Boost provides [`boost::container::set/map/multiset/multimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/container/configurable_containers.html#container.configurable_containers.configurable_tree_based_associative_containers) where the underlying binary-search-tree (BST) [can be configured](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/container/tree_type.html), and it can be chosen to be an AVL tree.

One (maybe the most crucial one) reason, why one would prefer AVL trees over Red-Black trees, is the `merge` and `split` operations of complexity `O(logN)`. However, surprisingly for me, it seems `boost::container` doesn't provide these operations. [The documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/container/set.html#idm45720955896192-bb) describes `merge` as an element-wise operation of `O(NlogN)` complexity (this is regardless of the underlying BST implementation!?), and the documentation doesn't even mention about `split`!

I can't say about `merge`, but as for `split`, I can assume that the lack of it might be justified by the constant-time `size` issue, so `split` of complexity `O(logN)` might not be aware of the sizes of the two resulting parts. But this could be fixed having an intrusive container and holding the sub-tree nodes count with each node.

There is also [`boost::intrusive::avl_set`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/intrusive/avl_set_multiset.html), but I couldn't find the AVL `merge` and `split` algorithms in [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/avl_set.html).

So the questions are.

1. Is there a full-functional, ready-to-go AVL based implementation of `set/map/multiset/multimap` that provides `merge` and `split` operations with the complexity of `O(logN)`?
2. If not, how can I build one using `boost::intrusive::avl_set`?

Comment: This might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029894/red-black-tree-split-concatenate-in-logn-time